# Transfer of data from the button to the post form on the next page. Django

Tags: django, forms

I am trying to pass the get parameter from the previous page assigned to my button to the next page add it to my form and save it in my database. My code looks like this:

**views.py**

```
def massage_order(request):
    parametr_html_product_name = request.GET('parameter')
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'btn_massage_order' in request.POST:
        ordering_form = OrderingMassageForm(data=request.POST)
        if ordering_form.is_valid():
        massage_product = parametr_html_product_name
        [...]
    else:
        ordering_form = OrderingMassageForm()
```

**templates.html**

```
<a href="{% url 'app:massage_order' %}?parameter={{ product.name }}&parameter_1={{ product.price }}&parameter_2={{ product.time }}&parameter_3={{ masseur.name }}">
    <div class="btn-group btn-action-label" role="group" aria-label="Like">
        <div class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary btn-label">{{ product.price }} zł/ {{ product.time }} min</div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-action">
            <span>Zamów masaż</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</a>
```

But I receive a mistake every time 'Multi Value Dict Key Error' i found his solution `parametr_html_product_name = request.GET.get('parameter', False)` 
but in this situation, my variable is False and not the name of the product (what it expects). How can I pass the variable 'html parameter product name' to my form? I tried to add it to the list (also without a positive effect). Any help will be appreciated.

Why, despite adding a variable to the Django list, does not it see in my form?

```
list = [parametr_html_masseur_name, parametr_html_product_name]

[...]
massage_product = list[1]
[...]
```

**EDIT**

**templates.html**

```
<form action="." method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="{{ product.name }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="{{ product.price }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="{{ product.time }}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="btn-group btn-action-label" role="group" aria-label="Like">
        <div class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary btn-label">{{ product.price }} zł/ {{ product.time }} min</div>
        <button type="submit" name="hidden_btn" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-action">
        <span>Zamów masaż</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**forms.py**

```
class HiddenOrderingMassageForm(forms.Form):
    product_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    price = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    time = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

**views.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST' and 'hidden_btn' in request.POST:
    hidden_form = HiddenOrderingMassageForm(request.POST)
    if hidden_form.is_valid():
        product_name = hidden_form.cleaned_data['product_name']
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:massage_order', args=[product_name]))
else:
    hidden_form = HiddenOrderingMassageForm()
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^massage_order/(?P<text>[\w\-]+)/$', views.massage_order, name='massage_order')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current code, you are using `GET` (as everything is wrapped in `<a>` tag), yet you expect the values to be in `request.POST`. I think that the best way to do it would be to use a form with hidden inputs with all values as you require, and validate them on backend, as you do with form. So, instead of using `a`, change to something following:

```
<form action="{% url 'app:massage_order' %}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="product_name">
    ...
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="btn-group btn-action-label" role="group" aria-label="Like">
        <div class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary btn-label">{{ product.price }} zł/ {{ product.time }} min</div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-action">
            <span>Zamów masaż</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Or, instead of creating the form manually in the template, you could specify an `OrderingMassageForm` which would have all fields' widgets set to hidden input, i.e.:

```
class HiddenOrderingMassageForm(forms.Form):
    product_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

and then put in the template in usual way:

```
<form action="{% url 'app:massage_order' %}" method="post">
    {{ hidden_form }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="btn-group btn-action-label" role="group" aria-label="Like">
        <div class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary btn-label">{{ product.price }} zł/ {{ product.time }} min</div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-action">
            <span>Zamów masaż</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but how can I use variables in the view? I added the code that you entered into the forms and then edited my template as described. I do not have any action, the button does not work.

Comment: @MaddieGraham try changing the type of the button to submit: `<button type="submit" ...`

Comment: it still does not work. I added my view after editing above, maybe you can see some of my mistakes, what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You mixed both solutions, if you created the form render it just using `{{ hidden_form}}`, or change the `name` attrs for the input tags in your template.